# node.js Error handling. storing error message in err instead of automatically printing it to console

Tags: node.js, error-handling, promise, try-catch

in the following code, i created an error

```
db.collection('deals').findOne({"_id":"8976889"})
.then(function(dealsInfoResult){
    throw Error("THIS IS THE ERROR");
    return (dealsInfoResult);
})
.catch(function(err){
    console.log("ERRRR: " + err);
    res.send(err);
})
```

});

after the error occurs, *err* does not have any error message, its empty. Rather "Error: This is the Error" is printed
In case of any error, i want the error to be stored in *err* so that i can handle it in my way.

Comment: It *does have an error message*, it's "THIS IS THE ERROR". The error is stored in `err`...

Comment: I understand err should contain the error message but the err is empty. Thats the issue.

Comment: err.message will contain the string

Comment: Thanks. @PeterVC . err.message solved the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use err.message to see the string.